# Filesystem root is saying its full, here is output to dh -f

Tags: partitioning, gparted

So, I've been trying to workout why it is saying filesystem root is full. I've tried autoclean and clean on this and on the main VM's I use. Could anyone advise me on what all these "loop"s are in this list? And also if this line is significant `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  914G  866G  1.7G 100% /`. Thanks.

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        3.2G  2.3M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  914G  866G  1.7G 100% /
tmpfs                         16G  144M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop3                    97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop0                   105M  105M     0 100% /snap/brackets/138
/dev/loop5                   234M  234M     0 100% /snap/atom/260
/dev/loop1                   234M  234M     0 100% /snap/atom/259
/dev/loop7                    97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/loop4                    70M   70M     0 100% /snap/cherrytree/28
/dev/loop10                  256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop6                    55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop2                    70M   70M     0 100% /snap/cherrytree/22
/dev/loop8                   141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/100
/dev/loop9                   106M  106M     0 100% /snap/electrum/2
/dev/loop11                  161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop13                  110M  110M     0 100% /snap/woe-usb/21
/dev/loop16                  2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop18                  4.0M  4.0M     0 100% /snap/hw-probe/828
/dev/loop19                  4.0M  4.0M     0 100% /snap/hw-probe/755
/dev/loop17                  256K  256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9
/dev/loop21                   49M   49M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
/dev/loop14                  256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/loop15                   68M   68M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/85
/dev/loop23                  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop12                   63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop25                  2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
/dev/loop22                  256K  256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
/dev/loop20                  162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop24                   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/sda2                    705M  428M  226M  66% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M   39M  473M   8% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        3.2G   24K  3.2G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                        3.2G   40K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: The /dev/loopXX entries are snaps you have installed. The "`/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 914G 866G 1.7G 100% /`" line is very significant. It's telling you that your filesystem is full.  Running clean and autoclean rarely frees up much space.

Comment: You're probably getting this error because there is not enough free space.  This can cause long-lasting damage to an installed system, and maybe already has.  You should free space by deleting unnecessary files, and don't forget to empty the trash and temp folders.  The damage may already be done, so you may ultimately end up needing to reinstall the entire operating system. Prevention is better than the current scenario: in the future always keep headroom to allow your root directory to function properly

Comment: Use your Desktop Search to find Disk Usage Analyzer. That will show you what is taking up all your hard drive space.